How object literals are different from json object?
I was defining a computed property in json object but json treats that property as a string but it works totally fine in object literal, so this makes me curios to know more about of it.
personType = 'student'

const json = '{
'name' : 'jane',
'age' : 20,
'[personType === 'student' ? 'studingAt' : 'workingAt']' : personType === 'student' ? 'oxford university' : 'Audi',
}'

here i am unable to assign computed value for key , which was fine in normal object literals.

Because a JSON is just a string that must obey JSON format specification. That's totally different from a javascript object. It just "looks" the same, but they are 2 completely different things. That's why you have JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, to convert a javascript object to a JSON string and vice versa. In short: JSONs don't have computed properties as they don't even have variables, because is not code, is just a string.

If you want to create a computed property in a JSON string from code, just append the variable inside the JSON string as you would normally do with whatever string, like so: const json = "{ 'name': 123, '"+ variable + "': 124 }";. By the way, is better to have a javascript object and just convert it to a JSON string by using JSON.stringify(myObject)

@JorgeFuentesGonzález I think creating object literal then converting it to json string using JSON.stringify(myObject) would be great way to resolve my problem.  thank for the explanation.

Glad to help ^^
